# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo giving me an error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get the images and videos from the device and trying to declare the `UIImagePickerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` but on the line `guard let...`, it gives me an error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String: Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

And on the line `let url = info...`, it gives me the same error.

How can I handle this?

```
//UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
extension SecondViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        guard let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String,
            mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
            let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
            else { return }

        dismiss(animated: true) {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            let vcPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
            vcPlayer.player = player
            self.present(vcPlayer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

//UINavigationControllerDelegate
extension SecondViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Always search on an error before posting. This has been asked and answered several times before.

Comment: @rmaddy Nope I have already searched and the concrete type of my error never been answered, there were similar questions concerning to UIImagePickerControllerDelegate but now Sh_Khan answered and it worked.

Comment: The others are duplicates. They show you the correct way to write the updated image picker delegate. Just because you happen to use a few other of the keys doesn't mean you couldn't have trivially figured out that trivial difference by looking at the obvious duplicates covering the **exact** same error message. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use latest syntax

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

guard let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? String,
    mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
    let url = info[.mediaURL] as? URL
    else { return }

    dismiss(animated: true) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let vcPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        vcPlayer.player = player
        self.present(vcPlayer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
}
```